# Swift Custom Struct missing argument "from: Decoder"

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

Hi I am using SwiftUI and trying to create an ObservableObject for one of my views.

```
class ResponseModelObject: ObservableObject {
    @Published var response = SongLinkAPIResponse()
}
```

The SongLinkAPIResponse looks like:

```
public struct SongLinkAPIResponse: Codable, Equatable {
    public var entityUniqueId: String
    public var userCountry: String
    public var pageUrl: URL
    public var entitiesByUniqueId: [EntityUniqueId:Entity]
    public var linksByPlatform: [Platform.RawValue:PlatformInfo]
}
```

However my problem is that I am getting an error `Missing argument for parameter 'from' in call` on the @Published property. The from property is a Decoder but I have not defined an init for SongLinkAPIResponse so I am not sure what to do?

I'm sure I am missing something simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conforming to `Codable` automatically creates `init(from:)` for your class.

`SongLinkAPIResponse()` is the same as `SongLinkAPIResponse.init()`.

You'd have to specify an initialiser in your class:

```
init() {
    // init properties here
}
```

Alternatively you can provide default values for your properties:

```
public struct SongLinkAPIResponse: Codable, Equatable {
    public var entityUniqueId: String = "" // some default value
    ...
}
```

Comment: ahh makes sense so is there any way I can just create a blank instance of this object? There will be a function that makes a call to an API which I am going to decode into that object, but I need some initial object to begin with before that call is made

Comment: @HarryDay You can just provide default values, then you don't need an empty init. But when decoding a Codable class (eg. using a JSONDecoder) you don't have to create an empty object.